# Complex SQL Query with two tables and group by count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I need to write a complex query that involves two tables and I’m struggling to understand how to construct the query properly.

The table structure is as follows, along with sample data:

```
Table 1:
ID | Type | Size
A123 | Block | Medium
C368 | Square | Large
X634 | Triangle | Small
K623 | Square | Small
```

```
Table 2:
ID | Code | Description | Price
A123 | C06 | Sensitive Material | 99.99
A123 | H66 | Heavy Grade | 12.76
A123 | U74 | Pink Hue | 299.99

C368 | H66 | Heavy Grade | 12.76
C368 | G66 | Green Hue | 499.99
C368 | C06 | Sensitive Material | 99.99
C368 | K79 | Clear Glass | 59.99

X634 | G66 | Green Hue | 499.99
X634 | K79 | Clear Glass | 59.99
X634 | Z63 | Enterprise Class | 999.99

K623 | K79 | Clear Glass | 59.99
K623 | G66 | Green Hue | 499.99
K623 | X57 | Extra Piping | 199.99
```

The query should be based on the Type column from Table 1 primarily and then total the counts from Table 2 based on matching IDs.

The final output should be a count that looks like this for Type = Square:

```
Code | Description | Count
H66 | Heavy Grade | 1
G66 | Green Hue | 2
C06 | Sensitive Material | 1
K79 | Clear Glass | 2
X57 | Extra Piping | 1
```

How can I assemble this result using these two tables? Here is an initial query I've written - does this look correct? It produces a result similar to the example above, however I'm not certain it is 100% correct and captures all edge cases.

```
select code, description, count(*) as total
from
(
SELECT code, description
FROM db.options_list ops
INNER JOIN db.obj_list ON ops.ID = db.obj_list.ID
WHERE db.obj_list.type="Square"
) src
group by code
order by total desc
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a simple `join`/`group by` query:

```
SELECT ops.code, max(ops.description), count(*) as total
FROM db.options_list ops JOIN
     db.obj_list ol
     ON ops.ID = ol.ID
WHERE ol.type = 'Square'
GROUP BY ops.code
ORDER BY total desc;
```

Notes:

- All tables use table aliases.
- All column references are qualified.
- The delimiter for the string comparison is the standard single quote, rather than the non-standard double quote.
- All unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` are in the `GROUP BY`.
- The subquery is unnecessary.

Your query might work in some databases.  I do encourage you to follow best practices when writing queries, though.

Comment: Thank you, @gordon. This was spot on (and very helpful guidelines) - with one exception: I needed to remove ops.description from the Group By statement, otherwise it wasn't clustering by ops.code correctly because there could be slightly different descriptions even if the code is the same. I'm sorry I didn't mention that initially. Thank you!

Comment: @K997 . . . I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want joins and aggregation:

```
select op.type, ob.code, ob.description, count(*) cnt
from options_list op
inner join obj_list ob on op.id = ob.id
group by ol.type, ob.code, ob.description
```